# IBActions not working

Tags: iphone, ibaction

I have two buttons that are not performing the IBAction that they are programmed to do.  I have them correctly connected in Interface Builder, but when I click them in the simulator or on a phone, they do not perform their task.  No crashes, nothing.  Here is my code

MapDetailInfo.h:

```
@interface MapDetailInfo : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *name;
IBOutlet UITextView *address;
NSString * nameText;
NSString * addressText;
NSString * stringOne;
NSString * stringTwo;


IBOutlet UILabel *phoneNumber;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * nameText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * addressText;
@property (retain, nonatomic)  NSString * stringOne;
@property (retain, nonatomic)  NSString * stringTwo;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *phoneNumber;

- (IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)getDirections:(id)sender; 


@end
```

MapDetailInfo.m:

```
@implementation MapDetailInfo
@synthesize name, address, nameText, addressText, phoneNumber, stringTwo, stringOne;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *myWords = [addressText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"("]
                    ];

stringOne = [myWords objectAtIndex:1];
stringTwo = @"("; 


stringTwo = [stringTwo stringByAppendingString:stringOne];


self.name.text = nameText;
self.address.text = [myWords objectAtIndex:0];
self.phoneNumber.text = stringTwo; 

  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(callPhone:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Call Shop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(104.0, 332.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];


}


- (IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {

NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:stringTwo];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}

- (IBAction)getDirections:(id)sender {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current    Location&daddr=%@",self.address.text]]];    
}
```

I am pulling this view from an annotation in a map.  Everything works perfect accept for these two buttons not performing their task.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Try adding in a breakpoint or a log statement in your actions to see if it is their contents which are being ignored, or if they are actually not being called.

Comment: You connect theese IBActions to a button?

Comment: Yes.  I put two buttons in Interface Builder and Connected them to the appropriate acctiions

Comment: "Appropriate" means... `Touch Up Inside`?

Comment: correct... appropriate means that I connected the button to the action that I want them to do when they are "Touch up Inside".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the buttons were not working is because the URL's were incorrect.  If you run into the same problem, make sure your telephone number URL's are:

```
@"tel://5555555"
```

I had the parenthesis and dash inside of mine and that is why it would not pull up.  Also there was an error in my google URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any `UIButton` in your code. Did you use them ?

**Edit:**

I had suggested that you use buttons for that is the specific purpose. And yes, you can still use labels and follow the same procedure to call the methods.

There has to be some issue with the way you are connecting the outlets.

I would suggest that you follow tutorials - 4, 5, and 6 of this Youtube link.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7jB0D3Y7Ws&feature=relmfu

Comment: I placed and connected two buttons in interface builder.  Would you think doing it in my code would work better?

Comment: No. If he doesn't need them, he shouldn't. _@Edit: Idan was first... :)_

Comment: He could use the methods with labels, But isn't his entire purpose to have a button that would call a method ? I would suggest that he use UIButtons. Seriously !

Comment: So I added a UIButton and the same thing happened.  Click the button and there's no action.

Comment: @Legolas: The button is in the IB file, and is connected to a method, it DOES show and it DOES perform the method, there's no need to declare it.

Comment: @ Legolas - those videos described how to do everything I have already done in my coding and in interface builder.  Does anyone really no what is wrong?  thanks all for the help though!

Comment: Try NSLogging inside the IBActions to see if they are atleast called.

Comment: yes.  when the IBActions are being called... the NSLogs appeared.

Comment: Good. Then it means that the touches are working. Problem Solved. What is your purpose for your buttons ? Just open a link ?

Comment: yes... one link is to call a phone number and the other is to open google maps... i  have ran it on both the simulator and an actual phone and both are not responding...

Comment: @Legolas IBAction and IBOutlets are completely independent.